# SQL Query to return count of Author, Customer for list of Books

Tags: mysql, count

trying to segregate the Authors and Customer count with respective to book

```
select Book, count(Author) as Author, count(Customer) as Customer 
from Books 
group by Book 
order by Book Asc;
```

but, resulting same values for customer and Author

| SNo | Book | Author | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A Study in Scarlet | Arthur Conan Doyle | Perry mason |
| 8 | Careless Kitten | Erle Stanley Gardner | Agatha Christie |
| 20 | Careless Kitten | Erle Stanley Gardner | Sherlock Holms |
| 16 | Gitanjali | Rabindranath Tagore | Mark Twain |
| 21 | Gitanjali | Rabindranath Tagore | Perry Mason |
| 22 | Gitanjali | Rabindranath Tagore | Miss Marple |
| 23 | Gitanjali | Rabindranath Tagore | Perry Mason |
| 3 | Gora | Rabindranath Tagore | Miss Marple |
| 10 | Gora | Rabindranath Tagore | Miss Marple |
| 4 | Murder on the Orient Exp | Agatha Christie | Miss Marple |
| 5 | Murder on the Orient Exp | Agatha Christie | Mark Twain |
| 13 | Peril at End House | Agatha Christie | Arthur Conan Doyle |
| 17 | Peril at End House | Agatha Christie | Mark Twain |
| 18 | The Adventures of Huckle | Mark Twain | Arthur Conan Doyle |
| 6 | The Adventures of Tom | Mark Twain | Agatha Christie |
| 14 | The Adventures of Tom | Mark Twain | Agatha Christie |
| 9 | The Gilded Age | Mark Twain | Perry Mason |
| 11 | The Gilded Age | Mark Twain | Perry Mason |
| 11 | The Gilded Age | Mark Twain | Perry Mason |
| 12 | The Gilded Age | Mark Twain | Perry Mason |
| 15 | The Gilded Age | Mark Twain | Rabindranath Tagore |
| 2 | The Murder of Roger Ack | Agatha Christie | Erle Stanley Gardner |
| 7 | The Murder of Roger Ack | Agatha Christie | Arthur Conan Doyle |
| 19 | The Sign of Four | Arthur Conan Doyle | Harry Potter |

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: It's not a kindness. It's the basic expectation.https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sample data should, almost always, not be provided through pictures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `COUNT` function in your query return quantity of not NULL values in columns `Author` and `Customer`. Because all records are not NULL you got equal values.
For calculate count of different values `COUNT(DISTINCT <column>)` should be used.

```
select 
    Book, 
    count(distinct Author) as AuthorsCnt, 
    count(distinct Customer) as CustomersCnt 
from Books 
group by Book 
order by Book Asc;
```

Check [SQL here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=2060e620ef07297a7be9e33413c3256e&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)